# Get picture data from Image control WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm new to WPF. I was programming for Windows Forms Applications, and there was Picture Box with Image property. But in WPF there is Image instead of Picture Box. How to get it's value? I mean the image data.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that by using [Image.Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source.aspx) property.

You will find a lot of samples on internet about it. For example code below sets image source, you can get the image similarly

```
Image myImage3 = new Image();
BitmapImage bi3 = new BitmapImage();
bi3.BeginInit();
bi3.UriSource = new Uri("smiley_stackpanel.PNG", UriKind.Relative);
bi3.EndInit();
myImage3.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
myImage3.Source = bi3;

  //get the source
  BitmapImage imgSource = myImage3.Source;
```

Comment: What next? I need to create picture and convert into byte array

Comment: @Timur - I suggest you update the question to say that; getting image data in a byte array is not very straightforward: do you mean raw uncompressed image data? In what format exactly?  Or do you mean the raw file data, which may be compressed, etc?